# How to horizontal listview scrolling control?

Tags: android

In my horizontal **listview** when I swipe one once, the scrolling is working as it should be, but what I need is  after a one swipe, next list item to be shown.(just like **trimmedia** preview in android )

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the fling method of your ListView.
The method "fling" is used to emulate the inertia of the list when you remove your finger from the screen. If the method is empty, this has the effect to scroll only on the next item.
Here an example:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;

public class MyListView extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public MyListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void fling(int velocityX) {
        //super.fling(velocityX);
    }

}
```

I didn't test but it's how I did in a little more complex on another project.